Import jar that uses Maven in Android Studio
I've finished a Maven Project that includes a SpringBoot Server.
I packed the server into a jar and it's runnable.
After running it from my phone and it worked, I thought it would be nice to have an App to do that just a little better and more convenient.
I tried adding the server jar as a dependency in my Android Studio Project but it doesn't work.
Just adding the dependency throws errors, after hours of searching for solutions I don't know what to do.
I don't know much about Gradle but I figured I should add the jar in build.gradle.kts under dependencies:
dependencies {
   implementation(files(libs/server.jar))
}

Doing this throws the following error:

Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexFileDependenciesTask$DexFileDependenciesWorkerAction
Error while dexing.

It also throws

Invalid build configuration. Attempt to create a global synthetic for 'Record desugaring' without a global-synthetics consumer.

I didn't change the default built.gradle or settings.gradle, other than adding the little snippet above in built.gradle.
My jar uses the Maven dependencies for springboot, gson and json internally.
